# Latex in Russian

Tags: transliteration

I want to use LaTeX in Russian: first of all I want to type in cyrillic in the source file (and see cyrillic in that source, not an english transliteration) and of course to get cyrillic after compilation. I would be grateful for a sample class as well as a list of packages that I need to download.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use plain old LaTeX, you can use [this wikibook](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) to start. You need to use multiple packages to solve internationalization problems.

However, if you start from scratch, I recommend using newer engines like Xe(La)TeX, or Lua(La)Tex, which have built-in internationalization. Here’s a Russian [wikibook](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/XeLaTeX) with introduction to XeTeX, and here’s an English [guide to LuaTeX](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use the `babel` package in LuaLaTeX, together with a TrueType or OpenType font that supports Cyrillic.  Save your document in UTF-8.

This lets you use any fonts that you can in your word processor.  (On Windows, though, make sure it’s installed for all users and not just for yourself.)

```
\documentclass{book} % Or whatever is appropriate
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\babelprovide[main, import=ru]{russian}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
% Substitute your fonts of choice:
\babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{sf}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\babelfont[russian]{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Матема́тика}

Матема́тика (др.-греч. μᾰθημᾰτικά < μάθημα «изучение; наука»)---наука
об отношениях между объектами, о которых ничего не известно, кроме
описывающих их некоторых свойств,---именно тех, которые в качестве
аксиом положены в основание той или иной математической теории.
Исторически сложилась на основе операций подсчёта, измерения и
описания формы объектов.

\end{document}
```

[image: Russian sample]

I made that a little more complicated than it needed to be, so that it would extend to the general case.  In practice, you could probably replace all the `\babelfont` commands with `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` and everything would work.

This gets you sensible default settings, but you’ll want to customize it for your own purposes.  In particular,

- You probably want to change the fonts.
- You want to tweak the `\babelfont` commands to enable the features of the fonts you choose.  The `fontspec` documentation lists all the available features, and the `otfinfo` command will tell you which ones any given font supports.
- For example, the CMU fonts (Computer Modern Unicode) are unusual in that they support ligatures if you select a script, but not by default.   This is an annoying bug, because it makes you re-declare that font for each language in order to get ligatures.  For most fonts, a second declaration for `\babelfont[russian]` is unnecessary.
- You’ll get some error messages saying, `Language 'Russian' not available for font 'CMUSerif' woth script 'Cyrillic.'`  These are harmless, but you can suppress them by adding a `Language=Default` option along with `Ligatures=Common`.
- The `microtype` package is optional, but cuts down drastically on the amount of hyphenation you need.  In my opinion, it makes your documents look a lot better.

Publishers in 2019 should no longer be forcing you to use PDFLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX.  It is possible to do, with enough kludges.  Here is a conversion of that example:

```
\documentclass{book} % Or whatever is appropriate
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[X2, LGR, T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage[greek, russian]{babel}
  \usepackage{microtype}

\else
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{microtype}

  \babelprovide[main, import=ru]{russian}
  \babelprovide[import]{greek}

  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
  % Substitute your fonts of choice:
  \babelfont{rm}[Scale=1.0]{CMU Serif}
  \babelfont[russian]{rm}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Serif}
  \babelfont{sf}{CMU Sans Serif}
  \babelfont[russian]{sf}[Ligatures=Common]{CMU Sans Serif}
  \babelfont{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
  \babelfont[russian]{tt}{CMU Typewriter Text}
\fi

\begin{document}

\chapter{Матем\'{а}тика}

Матем\'{а}тика (др.-греч. \foreignlanguage{greek}{μᾰθημᾰτικά} <
\foreignlanguage{greek}{μάθημα} «изучение; наука»)---наука об отношениях
между объектами, о которых ничего не известно, кроме описывающих их
некоторых свойств,---именно тех, которые в качестве аксиом положены в
основание той или иной математической теории. Исторически сложилась на
основе операций подсчёта, измерения и описания формы объектов.

\end{document}
```

[image: PDFLaTeX Sample]

Because PDFLaTeX uses several different, obsolete, 8-bit encodings that aren’t compatible with any other software, you have only [a handful of Cyrillic fonts available.](https://www.ctan.org/topic/font-cyrillic)  (Unless you want to convert another OpenType font to Type-1 and the T2A encoding yourself, and the license allows you to.)  Most of these are based on Computer Modern, but there are also conversions of Times, Utopia, Libertine, DejaVu and a few others.